# UTF-8 is not a supported encoding name in HTML Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc;
doc = web.Load("https://facebook.com");
```

Using HTML Agility Pack, it works fine on Google and other sites, but not Facebook or Twitter.  On those sites it gives error: "Additional information: '"utf-8"' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."

I guess these websites are blocking the requests.  I searched this error, but none of the solutions were on point.  Is there a solution or workaround?